# Recommended strategy to create multi-page form in Spring MVC with client-side state

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am intending to have a number of wizard-like forms which go through different pages on my web application. The application is built in Spring MVC with Thymeleaf for views, and some Spring Integration sprinkled here and there.

I took a look at Spring Webflow as a possible solution for this, but I absolutely don't like the Stateful part of it. The rest of my application is entirely stateless, and I'd definitely like to keep it that way.

Are there any possible solutions for this? For example somehow using Spring Webflow in a way where the information of previous screens is saved in some hidden form, or am I forced to roll a custom form solution for every "Wizard" I have on my website?

I can't turn it into one big form, because I need validation after the first bit before the second bit can be filled in.

This is the scenario I currently have (and will be replicated a couple of times on the website)

You have the first form where you can enter a number of answers to questions, after entering, these should be validated and you should be led to a second page with a number of other questions, along with a small text whose content depends on the questions answered on the first page (the questions on the second page are still the same). After answering those, they should also be validated, which will bring you to a third form, which is basically the payment form.

Comment: Use the client... Store it on the client side... Use a javascript framework to create your wizards and store the in between data on the client. Post everything at once at the end of your wizard. In theory you could replace parts of Spring Web Flow and have it store the state on the client in a cookie, but cookies are insecure and limited in size not to mention they provide some overhead in each request that is going to the server.

Comment: Your application isn't stateless if you need to store state. Either store it on the server or on the client. If the data is sensitive or some parts shouldn't be changed by the client then you need to store it on the server

Comment: I probably worded it wrong, I simply don't want state on my server side :-) Definitely not looking to move to a Javascript framework... Maybe I should just turn the whole thing into one massive form, split it up into divs and use show/hide to build it up, while doing AJAX checks on part of the form. Somehow.

Comment: Can't really comment well without knowing the idea behind the forms, but from a user perspective, that sounds pretty cumbersome to have numerous divs on one page without an option to save and return to it later.    If Webflow isn't an option, can you just use pure Spring MVC and post each page?  (With the understanding that you'd lose some benefits of Webflow?)

Comment: Well, I was considering to do the posting, and saving the information on a hidden form on the following page. But I feel like that would result in a lot of code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum wrote, you should take a look at some javascript framework. One good solution is to use AngularJS together with UI-Router extension. This allows you to create a state machine that will make your wizards highly readable.

For example, the definition of steps in your wizard could look similar to what is shown in the [UI-Router getting started section](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/). You would just need to post the data from the current state on each state transition for validation. This could be achieved by posting the data using the `resolve` attribute of the new state. This way any promises that will result from posting the data will be resolved before the transition actually runs. You could then just use error handlers to send the user back to the previous step when validation fails.

Comment: I have experience with AngularJS 1.3 and I know it is capable to do this, but honestly, I absolutely don't want to use a Javascript framework to do this. I have no trust in the way they are managed, at all.